# Need help setting up setintervals for my clicker game

Tags: javascript, html

So i have a clicker game set up where when you click a button you gain 1 point but im having a hard time setting up a 2nd button that costs points to buy then that function tied to that button should start increaseing your points by 1 every second.

I tired this ( ignore the function names / if statements):

```
function wolfXpUp(wolfChecked) {
 clearInterval(wolfInterval);

 if (wolfChecked && WolfCexp < WolfMexp) {
wolfInterval = setInterval(function () { wolfXpUp(wolfChecked); }, 200);
WolfCexp = WolfCexp + 1;
document.getElementById("WolfCexp").innerHTML = WolfCexp;
```

I tried to reformat this so it works with my buy ant function but i can't get it to work. the set interval should only go off after the function is bought.

JavaScript:

```
var cookies = 0;
var Strength = 1;

function cookieClick(){
cookies = cookies + Strength;
document.getElementById("cookies").innerHTML = cookies;
checkCursor()
};


var ants = 0;

function buyAnt(){
var antCost = Math.floor(10 * Math.pow(1.1,ants));     //works out the 
cost of this cursor
    if(cookies >= antCost){                                   //checks 
that the player can afford the cursor
        ants = ants + 1;                                   //increases 
number of     cursors
        cookies = cookies - antCost;                          //removes 
the cookies spent
        document.getElementById('ants').innerHTML = ants;  //updates the 
number of cursors for the user
        document.getElementById('cookies').innerHTML = cookies;  //updates 
the number of cookies for the user
    };
var nextCost = Math.floor(10 * Math.pow(1.1,ants));       //works out the 
cost of the next cursor
document.getElementById('antCost').innerHTML = nextCost;  //updates the 
cursor cost for the user
};
```

HTML:

```
 <span id="cookies">0</span>
            <br />
            <span id="rebirths">0</span>
            <br />
            <button onclick="cookieClick(); Strengthexp()">Click Me! 
    </button>
            <br />
            Cost: 10mp <button id="BigClickBtn" 
onclick="Bigclick()">BigClick</button>
            <br />
            Cost: <span id="antCost">10</span> <button onclick="buyAnt()" 
id="antCostBtn" >Buy Ant</button> <span id="ants">0</span>
```

I expect after buying the ant function for cookies to start going up by 1 every second. But my current output i can't get this to work.

Comment: You shouldn't use `setInterval`. You should use a single repeating function and call `Date.now()` to determine how much time has passed, allowing your calculations to be infinitely more accurate.

Comment: How would i do that? i've never used that before. i want a good way to have a sort of upgrade after buying the ant button and onwards if i make more buy buttons. i want after buying the ant button for the cookie count to start going up automatically by 1 every second

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol so i have this http://prntscr.com/o0pp6q   . I want it to be 1 every 1000 milliseconds. then 2 every 1000 milliseconds and so on every time u buy the ant thing. but at the moment its increasing the speed as well. i want it to always be 1000. if it just started doing 2 then 3 then 4 etc everytime i used that button that would be good.